# Confusion with Complex Equations

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the equation $z^6+8=0$. So what I did was I turned it into $z=\sqrt2(\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}))$ Now here is where I get confused. Do I simply input this into De Moivre's formula and get $$z^6=\sqrt2^6(\cos(\frac{\pi}{6}6)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}6))$$
$$= 8(\cos(\pi)+isin(\pi)) = -8$$ Don't I need $n-1$ answers not just one? Edit: As you can see it just keeps going as $k$ gets bigger. I also accidentally skipped $k=1$, so ignore that.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean $6$ answers (or $5$ **more** answers).

Comment: $-8 = 8e^{i\pi}, 8e^{i3\pi}, \cdots$ not just the first one.

Comment: You are doing things somewhat upside down as it seems. By some magic you give the solution $z=\sqrt2(\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}))$, and then use the De Moivre formula to check that it verifies the equation. It's the other way: De Moivre allows you to find the solution by writing $(\rho e^{i\theta})^6=\rho^6e^{6i\theta}=-8=8e^{i\pi+2k\pi}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well I think our professor told us to write the complex number in polar form and then use the formula to find the solutions. He never really used the exponential ($e$) but rather the formula wikipedia gives. I truly just do not understand what I am doing wrong. I am confused as to where I begin. Also what is this $\mathcal{p}$?

Comment: Carefully read the last equations and make the connection with De Moivre. (I used the exponential notation just as a shorthand, you can expand it). $\rho$ is the modulus of the solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hmmmm. So here is what I did: I turned the equation $z$ into polar form with use of the modulus $r$ and the angle $\theta=\pi/6$. Then, I used the formula to take the sixth power. Thus, I have 5 different $z_k$ which give -8 when plugged back into the original equation. Is this the wrong way to go about it? I will post a picture. But now I am starting to notice that I am doing something wrong, because as I let $k$ continue to get bigger, it goes infinitely and does not seem to end at $k=5$

Comment: No it goes periodically.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I posted my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us express the solution in polar form $z=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, where $\rho$ and $\theta$ are unknown.

The equation is $z^6+8=0$, hence

$$\left(\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)\right)^6=-8=8(\cos\pi+i\sin\pi).$$
Using De Moivre,
$$(\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))^6=\rho^6(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^6=\rho^6(\cos6\theta+i\sin6\theta).$$
Then by equating the modulus and the argument,
$$\rho^6=8\implies\rho=\sqrt2,$$
$$6\theta=\pi\implies\theta=\pi/6.$$
This does not exhaust the solutions because we can add any multiple of $2\pi$ in the expression of $-8$ without changing the result:
$$-8=8(\left(\cos(\pi+2k\pi)+i\sin(\pi+2k\pi)\right).$$
So any $\theta$ such that
$$\theta=(\pi+2k\pi)/6$$
gives a solution. By the periodicity of the circular functions, there are $6$ distinct cases, given by:
$$\begin{align}
k=0,z&=\sqrt2\left(\sqrt3+i\right)/2\\
k=1,z&=\sqrt2\left(i\right)\\
k=2,z&=\sqrt2\left(-\sqrt3+i\right)/2\\
k=3,z&=\sqrt2\left(-\sqrt3-i\right)/2\\
k=4,z&=\sqrt2\left(-i\right)\\
k=5,z&=\sqrt2\left(\sqrt3-i\right)/2\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

We know $m$ degree equation has exactly $m$ roots for integer $m>0$

[Euler identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity): $e^{i\pi}=-1$ more generally, $(e^{i\pi})^{2r+1}=-1$ for integer $r$

$$z^6=-8=(\sqrt2)^6e^{(2n+1)i\pi}$$ where $n$ is any integer

$$\implies z=\sqrt2e^{\dfrac{(2n+1)i\pi}6}$$ where $n\equiv0,1,2,3,4,5\pmod6$

Comment: I don't understand how you got the $\frac{2n+1}{i\pi}$, my book doesn't use the exponential but rather leaves it in trig form.

Comment: @Frumpy, Please find the edited version

Comment: So is it generally $z^n=r^n ( \cos(\theta + \frac{2k\pi}{n}) + i\sin(\theta + \frac{2k\pi}{n})$